# Run ASP.NET website on local IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm running Win 7 and I'm trying to get a ASP.NET website, to run under the local IIS. I've set up a virtual directory which points to the folder where the website is. But when I access localhost/[VirtualDir] I get an error from IIS. The error is a 401.3 and relates to not having rights to access the folder (my error message is in danish, so posting the error won't help much...grrrr). I've given IIS_IUSRS full rights to the folder with the code, but I still get the same error.

I've also tried to create a new default website in VS and place it in wwwroot, but I still get the same error.

Anyone who can help?

Best regards,
Steffen Jorgensen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably not the folder permission that are giving you the error, more likely it is the IIS authentication, below is a link with some steps to try.

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/HTTP-Error-4013-Unauthorized-Error-While-creating-IIS-70-web-site-on-Windows-Vista.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer.

Comment: Wauw...this is weird. After rebooting my PC it doesn't work again. The Anonymous Authentication is set to Application Pool Identity, but it does not work. Hmmm....

Comment: I didn't get it to work with the virtual directory, but I got it working under the default website under IIS - don't ask me why, but it seems there is some sort of permission problem, that I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 0):

have you told your project to use IIS in the project settings? The default is the special VS version of IIS (The name just escaped me), but if you'll go into Project Properties -> Web You'll see at the bottom that you want to change to "Use local IIS"